# Error in a C++(files and streams) program for creating a file

Tags: c++, fstream

I have written this program in order to create a file using `fstream` and the output should show either the file has been created or not. I have run it on several online compilers like **Codechef**,**C++** shell etc. The compilers has successfully compiled this program but the output is not coming accordingly, instead of saying file created compiler says error in creating file.
Can this be due to development tool?

Following is the code for this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream file; 

    file.open("a.txt");
    if(!file)
    {
        cout<<"Error in creating file!!!";

    }
    else 
    {
        cout<<"File created successfully.";
        file.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What operating system? What compiler? What compilation options?

Comment: It would seem to me that the file isn't in the same folder as the executable, therefore it can't find it to open it.  Also many online compilers will use command-line arguments instead of literals.

Answer (score 2):

`fstream.open()` will fail if the file does not exist.
To create the file if it doesn't exist

```
file.open("a.txt", ios_base::out);
```

Or use `ofstream`

```
ofstream file;
file.open("a.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

The [fstream constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/basic_fstreamhttp://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/basic_fstream) and [open function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open) open for read/write by default. The file must already exist to be opened in this mode. Instead, open for write:

```
file.open("a.txt", ios::out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program's behavior is probably depending upon the [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system). BTW, if you want to learn more about them, read [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/). Perhaps the current [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) already contains the file to be written or does not have the appropriate permissions (it should be writable to enable file creation). Details are operating system (and perhaps [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system)) specific. IIRC, some OSes ([Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows) probably) disallow opening a file which is already opened by some other process.

On Linux, you could use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to find out what system calls have failed (actually, it tells you all the [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) that have been executed by some given program or [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29)).

This is [probably] not *always* guaranteed by C++ standards (but see [sync_with_stdio](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio)), but many C++ standard libraries are above (and compatible with) the C standard library which sets [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) (see also [strerror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) and [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) ...) on *failure*; then you might try:

```
 fstream file; 

 file.open("a.txt", ios::out);
 if (!file) {
     // perror("a.txt");
     cout<<"Error in creating file!!!" << strerror(errno) << endl;
 }
```

Of course, as other answers told you ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40388410/841108) & [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40388475/841108)) you need the correct mode for [open](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open)...

See also [std::system_error](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_error)

Comment: The question does say it's attempting to _create_ a file.